# Check number of affected rows in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am trying to check in my model method if there was affected any rows if so return true else return false, but I don't know how to get it?:

```
class User_model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function save_new_user ($name, $email, $password)
    {
        $data = array(
            'name' => $name,
            'email' => $email,
            'password' => $password,
            'time' => time()
        );

        $this->db->insert('users', $data);

        // if (affected rows > 0) return true else return false
        if ([AFFECTED_ROWS] > 0) return true;
        else return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The method you are looking for is $this->db->affected_rows().

So your return statement could look like this:

```
return $this->db->affected_rows() > 0;
```

Comment: Or even `return $this->db->affected_rows() > 0;`

Comment: return $this->db->affected_rows()  will return 1 if UPDATE effected and return 0 if UPDATE not effected.