# Codeigniter - update query executed successfully but $this->db->affected_rows() returns false

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am working on a `Codeigniter` based web project where i need to update a user from admin panel. It works correctly if the updated value is different from the value already exists in database. The issue is that the `$this->db->affected_rows()` returns `TRUE` if the value is different but returns FALSE if the value is same.

Here's my code:-

```
// $where contains the array for where clause
// $data contains the array of user's data which includes the updated value

$this->db
        ->where($where)
        ->update('users', $data);

if($this->db->affected_rows() == true)
{
    $response = array(
        'message' => "User edited successfully",
        'status' => true
    );
}
else
{
    // this else block always get executed if the updated value is equal to the value already exists in database. But in reality the record was updated successfully

    $response = array(
        'message' => "Unable to edit user",
        'status' => false
    );
}

return $response;
```

Comment: How can you sure that "update query executed successfully"?

Comment: wouldnt that be the case? if the value is same with the one in the database it will not update, for that you need to change the modified time to make it work

Comment: @urfusion I have a time field in database which is using ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. So, the time is updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [transaction](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/transactions.html) to check if the query executed successfully or not. After that you can check the $this->db->affected_rows() to see if the admin really updated the user value or not, and return message accordingly.

**Updated Code:**

```
$this->db->trans_start();

    // $where contains the array for where clause
    // $data contains the array of user's data which includes the updated value

    $this->db
            ->where($where)
            ->update('users', $data);

$this->db->trans_complete();        

if($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
{
    $response = array(
        'message' => "Unable to edit user",
        'status' => false
    );
}
else
{
    if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0)
    {
        $response = array(
            'message' => "User edited successfully",
            'status' => true
        );
    }
    else
    {
        $response = array(
            'message' => "User edited successfully, but it looks like you haven't updated anything!",
            'status' => true
        );
    }
}


return $response;
```

Answer (score 0):

It will return `numeric` value, not `true` Please check using
 `if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0)`
Please read documentation [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/helpers.html)

Comment: for ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16909257/check-number-of-affected-rows-in-codeigniter

Comment: This is not the correct answer @metalbox because it is unaware of basic php.  `1` (more generally, any non-zero) is a "truthy" number and `0` is a "falsey" number.

Answer (score 0):

as per CI document `$this->db->affected_rows()` returns true if user has edit anything and return false if query is successfully executed but data didn't changed by user.

you just confirm that query has successfully run.if query is successfully run it means your data has been updated.

```
$result = $this->db
        ->where($where)
        ->update('users', $data);

if ( ! $result)
{
     // Error

}else{

     // Function ran ok - do whatever
         if($this->db->affected_rows() == true)
        {
            $response = array(
             'message' => "User edited successfully",
            'status' => true
             );
        } else {
          $response = array(
          'message' => "There is nothing to update",
           'status' => false
          );
     }

}
```

Comment: Chris Murphy,you can do one thing until user didn't change any value don't enable update button.